# Error when calling interface function?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "io"

type MyClass struct{
    writer  *io.Writer
}

func (this *MyClass) WriteIt() {
    this.writer.Write([]byte("Hello World!"))
}
```

Why is it that when `writer`, which is an implementation of `io.Writer`, tries to call the `Write()` function, displays me this error

> this.writer.Write undefined (type *io.Writer has no field or method
>   Write)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282741/golang-calling-methods-on-interface-pointer

Answer (score 5):

As makhov said, it is because `writer` in your struct definition of `MyClass` is a pointer to something which implements the Writer interface, not something which implements the writer interface itself. As such, your code should either be:

```
package main

import "io"

type MyClass struct{
    writer  io.Writer
}

func (this *MyClass) WriteIt() {
    this.writer.Write([]byte("Hello World!"))
}
```

or

```
package main

import "io"

type MyClass struct{
    writer  *io.Writer
}

func (this *MyClass) WriteIt() {
    (*(this.writer)).Write([]byte("Hello World!"))
}
```

Typically it would make sense (and be more idiomatic) to do the first option.

Answer (score 2):

Use `writer  io.Writer` without `*`